# How to pass TxOutDatumNone when building a script transaction with cardano-cli

Tags: smart-contract, cardano-cli, transaction, datum

I'm trying to consume a UTxO from a *script address*. When querying the script address with `cardano-cli query utxo`, I have the following UTxO:

```
                           TxHash                                 TxIx        Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10668bed901733bb0977ec72d1abad481865b34ea1c18302caaaa1eafe5784d2     1        1344798 lovelace + TxOutDatumNone
```

However, when constructing a transaction, I do not know how to represent `TxOutDatumNone`:

```
cardano-cli transaction build \
--alonzo-era \
...
--tx-in 10668bed901733bb0977ec72d1abad481865b34ea1c18302caaaa1eafe5784d2#1 \
--tx-in-datum-value WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE \
...
```

---

What I've tried:

- Not passing the `--tx-in-datum-value` altogether results in:

> Missing: (--tx-in-datum-file FILE | --tx-in-datum-value JSON VALUE)

- Passing `--tx-in-datum-value 0` results in:

> Command failed: transaction build  Error: The following scripts have execution failures:
> the script for transaction input 0 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with:
> The Plutus script witness for the txin does not have a script datum (according to the UTxO). The txin in question is 10668bed901733bb0977ec72d1abad481865b34ea1c18302caaaa1eafe5784d2#1

- Passing `--tx-in-datum-value null` results in:

> option --tx-in-datum-value: JSON schema error within the script data: null
> JSON null values are not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that presenting a "none" datum is not possible. This also means that this UtxO is lost (anybody, correct me if I'm wrong)

I don't know the very reason why it is possible to send a UtxO at a script address without datum hash, while at the same time it will not be possible to get it back. Anyway, pay attention to always send a datum hash when sending some value at a script address.

Comment: I'm leaning to think that's the case as well. But haven't been able to find a definite reference yet.

Comment: Found a confirmation to the statement here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/Alonzo-testnet/blob/0ecd57c14570a92c2f6cd102c12b59c99a01a954/Alonzo-tutorials/Datums_redeemer_tutorial.md?plain=1#L131

Comment: The reason for this is that in addition to Plutus scripts, there are also native scripts (which predate Plutus), and those don't require a datum. It's impossible to know, given just an address, whether a script address corresponds to a Plutus script or to a native script. Therefore the node can't enforce that UTxO's at Plutus script addresses always have a datum attached.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you want to pass empty datum to the script you'd pass an empty list like so

```
--tx-in-datum-value []
```

Comment: This gives me a similar error as passing `0`: Command failed: transaction build  Error: The following scripts have execution failures:
the script for transaction input 0 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with:
The Plutus script witness for the txin does not have a script datum (according to the UTxO). The txin in question is 10668bed901733bb0977ec72d1abad481865b34ea1c18302caaaa1eafe5784d2#1

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore it. You do not need to account for TxOutDatumNone in your tx-out or anywhere else. See for yourself by manually sending a TX using cli before you script it.

Comment: Do you mean not to pass the `--tx-in-datum-value` option to the `cardano-cli transaction build` command? Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Correct. It's not a required parameter, so if you aren't using it (which it doesn't sound like you are), then ignore it..?

EDIT: I see now that you say you've tried this and are getting an error which baffles me - I send hundreds of CLI transactions a day and have never seen that error come up. Are you able to provide your draft cli command TX?

Comment: Correct that I'm not using the datum. It seems to me that either of the datum options still has to be specified because the transaction is consuming a UTxO from a Plutus script address. The full command and accompanying script can be found at: https://gist.github.com/discosultan/c03a1ea29d8b3bec8b2825c8fd879afa